# Extrapolating pixel position form pixel value

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas, for-loop

I"m attempting to loop through the pixels in this black and white image and I've pieced together code that people have helped me come up with but I can seem to get the result I want. I'm trying to loop through the pixels of a PNG image of a white circle on a black background.
In the code, the loop should only be accessing the red values of the pixels and then logging their position in a separate array.

Could somebody please try and clean this code up or even provide their own way of doing this?
I'd like to know what it is I'm doing wrong. I'm a beginner at coding, and really need some help on the subject.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            can.width = img.width;
            can.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

        var w = ctx.canvas.width, h = ctx.canvas.height;
        var id = ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
        var d = id.data;
        for (var y = 0;y < h; ++y){
            for (var x = 0; x < w; ++x){

                var i=(y*w+x)*4;
                var r=d[i], g=d[i+1], b=d[i+2], a=d[i+3];

            }
        }
        }
        img.src = 'circle-image-alone-bw.png';



    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The image will be loaded and draw in the canvas async. That means the onload function may be called after you go through reading all the pixels.

Answer (score 2):

As the image data is arranged as quadruples (R, G, B, A) you can simply loop through like this:

```
for (var y = 0; y < d.length; y += 4) { /// skip 4 bytes each turn
    var red = d[y];
}
```

It you still get blank data (all 0's) then:

1) You didn't use onload properly:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    can.width = img.width;
    can.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    /// HERE go to getImageData
    getData();
}
img.src = 'circle-image-alone-bw.png';

function getData() {
    var w = ctx.canvas.width, h = ctx.canvas.height;
    var id = ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
    var d = id.data;
    for (var y = 0;y < h; ++y){
        for (var x = 0; x < w; ++x){

            var i=(y*w+x)*4;
            var r=d[i], g=d[i+1], b=d[i+2], a=d[i+3];

        }
    }
}
```

As image loading is async you risk not having access to the data when you execute your getImageData right after setting source. Therefor you need to wait until the image load is ready. Then execute the function.

2) probably [CORS (a security feature)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) kicked in preventing to get the image data by `getImageData()` or `toDataURL()`.

Images used by canvas must be of same origin. If other domain is used for image (and the server at that domain don't use access header) - or - file is loaded from file:// protocol, canvas is defined 'dirty', meaning you won't be able to get the data as byte array.

You can also check console for security errors.

To get around this problem there are three options:

1. Move the image to your own server so it loads from the same origin  as your page.
2. Modify source server to implement an accept-* header to allow loading the image from other origins (this is not so easy if you don't manage the server yourself).
3. Use your own server and page as a proxy: `http://myserver/getImage?http://otherserver`

There are no other ways around this.

Comment: yes I edited that, but what it is I cannot do is actually get the loop to go through the pixels in the image itself. I viewed the contents of d[i] and it was 45,000 zeros, so all black and no white values.

Comment: Just to complement the answer. Using his solution, you can get the position of the pixel using division and mod. Ex.: pos = y/4; real_y = Math.floor(pos/width); real_x = pos % width;

Comment: @user2517142 what can I say, this is how you loop through. Could you share the image you are trying this with as it is difficult to test without access to it. If your images is loaded from a different domain (or using file://) that would explaining blank image due to CORS.

Comment: @user2517142 as I mentioned in the comment of your code, you are looping before loading the image.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post the image. Here's the link to the image http://imgur.com/8UzWlWX

Comment: @wendelbsilva Ok so how do i make it loop after I've loaded the image?

Comment: @user2517142 Ken just answered that for your. Put your code to get the pixels in the "/// HERE go to getImageData"

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware I see. I had to make the loop within that first block of code. i didn't see the answer edit.

Comment: Sorry about that, SO didn't wanted to format the code properly, but I think it should be fine now.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware yeah I copied the second block into the first block and it said "the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data"